# How to undo Inertia.js from my Laravel application

Tags: npm, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I have a problem with undoing Inertia.js in my application. When I started my application, I accidentally typed both commands.

```
php artisan jetstream:install inertia --teams
```

After a while when I saw that Livewire would be more suitable for my project.

```
php artisan jetstream:install livewire --teams
```

I tried to delete all my Inertia.js components, but my `npm watch` will output errors. I am wondering what I should do to undo Inertia.js from my project completely?

Comment: Make sure to initially commit your Laravel application to a version control system like Git. Then when you make these system-wide changes, you can roll back those changes. There are a ton of files that Jetstream adds and updates. When you run that first command, currently you will see 18 file changes and 80 file additions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I see it you have 3 options:

1. Start over.  Reinstall Laravel and be sure you are installing ONLY the version you want.
2. If you used a version control system, revert and then go from there.
3. If you didn't use something like git, you could try deleting node_modules from your project, removing all the inertia packages, removing the auth scaffolding, dump the autoload, and try to reinstall without those packages.  But again, that's a LOT of work for hopes and dreams.  See 1 or 2.

You're so early on in the project that it makes the most sense.  If you want to copy your controllers and views you want to save to another folder before starting over, there you go.